# Turn off desktop screen/keyboard when connecting via VNC?

Tags: security, remote-desktop

When I VNC into a remote OS X machine (e.g. my office machine), the remote screen is showing everything I'm doing. It also unlocks the screen so that if I'm not watching that screen, someone can use the machine and get access to things I'd prefer them not to.

The usual method is somebody in the office pranking me by loading up a browser with cuteoverload and full screening it.

This bothers me since it isn't very secure.

Is there a way to turn off the physical screen/keyboard until I come back to the office? Or require someone to enter a password to use the remote screen/keyboard?